# SQLAlchemy what's the difference between creating an type instance and setting default values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I am learning SQLAlchemy and found different usages of defining types and how to set default values. What are the differences between them?

Example 1

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    age = sa.Column(
        sa.Integer,
        default=0,
    )
```

Example 2

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    age = sa.Column(
        sa.Integer(),
        default=0,
    )
```

and

Example 3

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    age = sa.Column(
        sa.Integer(0),
    )
```

Is there any difference in functionality between these examples or are they just syntactic sugar?

Comment: Your first two examples are equivalent. Your third example simply does not work: "TypeError: Integer() takes no arguments"

Comment: sorry about that, I saw this usage somewhere on the internet but probably it's outdated now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify, first two are equivalent because of magic/sugar explained in [sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.type_](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.type_):

> The column’s type, indicated using an **instance** which subclasses
> TypeEngine. If no arguments are required for the type, the **class** of
> the type can be sent as well

Usually `Integer` column types don't take arguments.  Mysql dialect takes some weird arguments but a better example might be `String` which commonly takes a [`length`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.String.params.length) argument.  This is not a default but information to configure the type for the column.

The `default` is configuration for the `Column` and not the type.

Not to add more confusion but [`default`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.default) is only used on the client side.  For a database server side default you must set [`server_default`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.server_default).

`String` is a better example that might look like this:

```py
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name1 = Column(String, default="anonymous")
    name2 = Column(String, server_default="anonymous")
    name3 = Column(String(15), server_default="anonymous")
```

Here is postgresql SQL output with the 3 different name columns (`SERIAL` is a special integer type for postgresql primary keys):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    name1 VARCHAR, 
    name2 VARCHAR DEFAULT 'anonymous', 
    name3 VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT 'anonymous', 
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `default is only used on the client side`? Let's say I have a FastAPI project, does that mean that FastAPI will use the `default` value and the database will use `server_default`? Also, what's the difference between `String(15)` and `String(), max_length=15`?

Comment: With `default `SQLAlchemy controls setting the default value if no value is given whereas with `server_default` the database server controls setting the default value if no value is given.  There are pros and cons to these two approaches.  Maybe create a script and test database and experiment with them.

Comment: I don't use fastapi but I think `max_length=15` is just for validating input before it goes into the database and doesn't involve SQLAlchemy at all.  Whereas String(15) defines how much can be stored in that column in the database.  SQLAlchemy doesn't really involve validation.